# Is it possible to create a directory and file inside /proc/sys?

Tags: centos, proc

I am running CentOS 6.2 and I need to create a subdirectory named "crypto" inside `/proc/sys`. Inside `/proc/sys/crypto`, I need to create a file named `test` which contains the value "1".

Comment: As per the other two answers, `/proc/` is a virtual filesystem. `/proc/sys/crypto` should appear magically the instant the kernel loads a driver that uses it. I suspect that you're actually missing something else -- can you elaborate as to what you're doing that tells you to create that file?

Answer (score 7):

[Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer is correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38267/is-it-possible-to-create-a-directory-and-file-inside-proc-sys/38273#38273): files under `/proc` and `/sys` are provided by the kernel. If you want to add a file there, write a kernel module. You can find a slightly dated presentation of the `/proc` programming interface in [*Linux Device Drivers*](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) 3rd ed. [ch. 4](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch04.pdf).

Technically, it is possible to jump through hoops to make a file appear in `/proc/sys/crypto` (or anywhere else, really). Make a [bind mount](http://docs.1h.com/Bind_mounts) from `/proc/sys/crypto` to a staging directory, and make a [union mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) of the staging directory and an overlay directory back onto `/proc/sys/crypto`. Here's an example using [unionfs-fuse](http://podgorny.cz/moin/UnionFsFuse).

```
# mkdir /tmp/original /tmp/overlay
# mount --bind /proc/sys/crypto /tmp/original
# unionfs-fuse -o nonempty /tmp/overlay=RW:/tmp/original=RO /proc/sys/crypto
# echo hello >/proc/sys/crypto/test
# cat /proc/sys/crypto/test
hello
# umount /proc/sys/crypto
# umount /proc/sys/crypto
# cat /tmp/overlay/test
hello
```

Note: I disclaim any responsibility for system or brain damage caused by experimenting with this stuff. The commands above are perfectly safe, but messing with other areas of `/sys` and `/proc` can cause weird behavior.

Answer (score 6):

`/proc` is a virtual filesystem. You will need to write a kernel module that creates the appropriate structures within it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do this, but if you do *need* to create a directory in /proc this is all you need in a kernel module

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>

static int procfoo_init(void) {
    proc_mkdir("foo", NULL);
    return 0;
}

module_init(procfoo_init);
```

Once you have a mount point in /proc you can bind a normal fs path to it and do what you like in the directory from userland.

```
mount --bind /var/lib/foo /proc/foo
```

This will break as soon as you upgrade the kernel, and almost certainly not what op requires, but here it is since this comes up in search engines.