# Can I add to /proc/self?

Tags: proc, mmap

I want to create a number of named memory regions in my program, and `mmap` them somewhere so that other processes can read them. I can't guarantee that only one instance of my program will run at a time. Ideally, I'd like to put the blocks under `/proc/self/<blockname>` or such. Is this possible? Or is there another place I can put the mapped files? (My program will normally not run as root.)

I don't want to use `/proc/self/fd` or `/proc/self/map_files`, since that doesn't allow naming them (as far as I know).

Comment: You may want to look at [POSIX shared memory](http://man7.org/training/download/posix_shm_slides.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot add your structure in a meaningful way to `/proc` because it is generated (not a "real" filesystem).  Likewise `/sys` on some machines.  Changing the structure of `/proc` isn't straightforward (see for example *[Creating a folder under /proc and creating a entry under the folder](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2012/01/creating-folder-under-proc-and-creating.html)*).

Further reading:

- *[Linux Filesystem Hierarchy:    Chapter 1. Linux Filesystem Hierarchy: 1.14. /proc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html)*
- *[mmap, munmap - map or unmap files or devices into memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)*
- *[Is it possible to create a directory and file inside /proc/sys?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38267/is-it-possible-to-create-a-directory-and-file-inside-proc-sys)*

@mark-plotnick suggested POSIX shared memory, which does support *names*.

Further reading:

- *[Posix shared memory vs mapped files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262815/posix-shared-memory-vs-mapped-files)* (versus mmap, for example)
- *[shm_overview - overview of POSIX shared memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)*
- *[shm_open,  shm_unlink  -  create/open  or  unlink POSIX shared memory objects](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html)* 
  (These are *named* objects)

  > The operation of `shm_open()` is analogous to that of [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).  name
  >   specifies the shared memory object to be created or opened.  For
  >   portable use, a shared memory object should be identified by a name
  >   of the form *`/somename`*; that is, a null-terminated string of up to
  >   `NAME_MAX` (i.e., 255) characters consisting of an initial slash,
  >   followed by one or more characters, none of which are slashes.
- *[shm_open - open a shared memory object (REALTIME)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)* (POSIX)

Answer (score 1):

No. The kernel decides what is in `/proc/PID`, not the process. (`/proc/PID` is what you're asking about, not `/proc/self`: other processes don't see your process in `/proc/self`.)

When processes need to convey data about themselves, the conventional place to put this information is under `/var/run` for processes started by the administrator (i.e. system services), and under `/tmp` or under the user's home directory for processes started by a user. For information tied to a process, the home directory is usually a bad idea because it can be shared between machines. Modern Linux systems also have `/run/user/UID`. Pick one and define a convention, e.g. a directory `/tmp/myapplication-1234` or `/run/user/myapplication/1234` where 1234 is the PID. Delete this directory when your process exits.