# Save variable from initramfs (at boot time)

Tags: boot, environment-variables, initramfs

How can I save environment variables at boot time before the real filesystem has been mounted ?

I know there is `/etc/environment` but whithin initramfs that file is not accessible yet. I also thought of writing a file to store the value but when that file exits on the system it's override after the real filesystem is mounted

Ps : I just want to store the variable for later, not to read it at boot time

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER**

Approximately :

- Create a kernel module (find help [here](https://blog.sourcerer.io/writing-a-simple-linux-kernel-module-d9dc3762c234) and [there](https://linux.die.net/lkmpg/c708.html)) nammed *mod.ko*
- Make sure the module is usable during boot time (by including it inside the kernel image with initramfs-tools or finding it within the filesystem)
- Add the following lines to your script

If you don't have included the module in the kernel image

```
insmod /path/to/mod.ko
```

Else directly

```
echo "env_var=value" > /proc/name_of_your_process
```

where `name_of_your_process` is the name given inside the `__init` of your module (when doing `entry = proc_create("name_of_your_process",0777,NULL,&my_fops);`)

Then later during the startup process in a script

```
cat /proc/name_of_your_process
>> env_var=value
rmmod mod.ko
```

Comment: Depends on what your initramfs looks like, but my first try would be `mkdir /run/envdump;  mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /run/envdump -o size=16m; env >/run/envdump/output` as an addition to `linuxrc` or whatever the script is your initramfs runs. There could be more to it and I cannot find out atm so this is just a comment ...

Comment: That works I can create a file in /run. But I'm afraid that the file I  create could be used by another process which need to create a file with the exact same name

Comment: However, I can create a directory on the filesystem (directory created by user), then mount a tmpfs over that directory (which will temporarily hide all files inside it) add my environment file inside the tmpfs, read that file at startup then write it into `/etc/environment` and finally umount the tmpfs. Of course, path to the user directory will be write into `/etc/environment` and read at boot time (since I have access to the RO `/root` filesystem)

Comment: So just to followup, you managed to store data inside of custom kernel module that never touched the root filesystem? Interesting.

Comment: Yes. I just edit the `/proc` inside my kernel image. The value is then read at startup and the module is unloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When initramfs cleans up all the files it runs [switch_root](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/switch_root.8.html) which will delete all of the files EXCEPT for the folders: /proc, /dev, /sys and /run. It may be possible to create a special file in one of those folders, but there is trickery involved.

See: [Is it possible to create a directory and file inside /proc/sys?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38267/is-it-possible-to-create-a-directory-and-file-inside-proc-sys)

Your easiest option of course, is to just add a script to write the variable to the filesystem after the root filesystem has been loaded but before init is run. This would go in the "[local-bottom](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html)" folder. Is there any reason you can't do this?

Comment: Because the `/root` is mounted as RO and if possible I would like to avoid messing with filesystem (remount as rw)

Answer (score 1):

Well, regular environment inheritance (just export it ...) would work in theory but... the problem is, whatever your *initramfs* is starting will probably clean up the environment on purpose, as that is usually done to make sure nothing odd is going on. Letting environment variables go unchecked can be a security hazard.

> I know there is `/etc/environment` but whithin initramfs that file is not accessible yet.

The fun part about *initramfs* is that you can do whatever you want. The only limitation is your imagination.

You can totally make the file accessible. Mount, modify, umount. Or if you are using a traditional filesystem - without checksums - you can even modify it *without* mounting anything (or at least not in read-write mode). Same trick GRUB uses for `grubenv`.

If you don't want to muck with the filesystem or physical storage in general, you could set up a ram disk or tmpfs or loop device or ... there are countless ways for initramfs to leave something behind (you usually have to make an effort to clean up).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Take a look at fstab. Then mount root device and write your variable to a file on the mounted root device. I learned this from kdump.